# Dynamic variables binding in mysqli bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

When I try to below code it give me a warning

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = ? AND fname = ?');
    $type = "ss";
    $param = array("Maq","bool");
    $params[] = &$type;
    $params[] = &$param;

    call_user_func_array( array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params );
```

I really don't know why its happening I read a lot of same title questions in Stack Overflow but some has comma separated types or need more type but in my case I think its proper but why I am keep getting warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = ? AND fname = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $param[0], $param[1]);
$stmt->execute();

//other version
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = ? AND fname = ?');
$type = "ss";
$names = array("Maq", "bool");
$params = array(&$type, &$names[0], &$names[1]);

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

Comment: i want it dynamically please :)

Comment: Like this ? About the call_user_func_array, please see : http://no2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#89171

Comment: thanks @Spoke44 but he is using procedural style i have to stuck with OOP :/

Comment: thankkkkk uu so much its working but what was the problem i did not get it??

Comment: The array params must contain only values. You passed to it an array of values !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68869/discussion-between-spoke44-and-maq).

Answer (score 5):

This is a late answer, I hope will help someone.

It's a part of my mysqliLayer class, so I extracted needed variables.

```
// establish mysqli connection
$conn = new mysqli(.....); 
$tableName = 'users';
// Types to bind
$type = 'isss';
$fields = ['id','name', 'email', 'created'];
$values = [1, 'angel', 'email@test.com', '2018-1-12'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (" . join(',', $fields) . ") VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// Using ...token introduced in php v.5.6 instead of call_user_func_array
// This way references can be omitted, like for each value in array
$stmt->bind_param($type, ...$values);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```